# Work in teams using MySql and xampp localhost - can't update the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, server

Me and some friends are working on a PHP page and we need a MySql database(we need to present the xampp localhost version). Since we will all make edits there we need a way to somehow update our local database with others work when they do it. 
I tried to export the database from them and import in my phpmyadmin but for this I have to delete my old database. Isn't there a method to just update it? I mean what can they make to send me a file with an update and how can I import just an update?
I tried to search the answer for hours but couldn't find something specific.

Comment: Just export the data not the Tables

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is to synchronize database table changes, not data.

You must read about migrations and don't interact database directly from PHPMyAdmin.

Phinx is the most popular tool in PHP about migrations.
https://phinx.org/